# Laravel Set up User Language

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-localization

I have many controllers and I want to set this code in the all of this(actually all of project), how can i do that?

```
if( !empty(Input::get('lan')) ){
  Auth::user()->language = Input::get('lan');
  App::setLocale( Auth::user()->language );
}else{
  App::setLocale( Auth::user()->language );
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware).

Comment: Yea, answer is middldware, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Laravel's middleware** for that. **Middleware** is a layer of code that wraps the request processing and can execute additional code before or/and after request is processed.

First, you need your middleware class. It needs to have one method called **handle()** that will do the desired logic. In your case it could look like that:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Auth;
use App;

class SetLang {
  public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    if(empty($request->has('lan'))) {
      if (Auth::user()) {
        Auth::user()->language = $request->input('lan');
        Auth::user()->save(); // this will do database UPDATE only when language was changed
      }
      App::setLocale($request->input('lan'));
    } else if (Auth::user()) {
      App::setLocale(Auth::user()->language);
    }

    return $next($request);
  }
}
```

Then register the middleware in your **App\Http\Kernel** class so that it gets executed for every request:

```
protected $middleware = [
    //here go the other middleware classes
    'App\Http\Middleware\SetLang',
];
```

You can find more info about **Middleware** in the docs here: http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware

Comment: it's work, but just another little question, why it save without this line: `Auth::user()->save();` I'm wondered!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that with newest versions of Laravel (im on 5.8) for this middleware to work you need to place it under `$middlewareGroups` otherwise the call to `Auth::user()`  its always empty.

Following **jedrzej-kurylo** answer, just move the middleware to:

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
                ...
                'App\Http\Middleware\SetLang',
        ],
];
```